# `chown -Rv tester .` will not change ownership of files

Tags: linux, root, chroot, lfs

The process keeps saying `retained as root` when I run `chown -Rv tester .`

How do I make file ownership switch from root to tester?

```
(lfs chroot) root:/sources/gcc-10.2.0/build# chown -Rv tester . 2>&1 | head -10
ownership of './x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/config.log' retained as root
ownership of './x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/scripts/testsuite_flags' retained as root
ownership of './x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/scripts/extract_symvers' retained as root
ownership of './x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/scripts' retained as root
ownership of './x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/doc/xsl/customization.xsl' retained as root
ownership of './x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/doc/xsl' retained as root
ownership of './x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/doc/Makefile' retained as root
ownership of './x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/doc' retained as root
ownership of './x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/multilib.out' retained as root
ownership of './x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/python/Makefile' retained as root
(lfs chroot) root:/sources/gcc-10.2.0/build#
```

This is the output of `id tester`:

```
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

Comment: What environment are you running in? And are you using remote file-systems?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor im not using a remote system

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov i posted the output

Answer (score 2):

The OP has said that:

```bsh
# id tester
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

Which means that the user `tester` is `root` in terms of permissions/security and `chown` doesn't have to do anything which is indicated in the chown output.

Please delete the user `tester` (`userdel tester`) and recreate it normally, e.g.

```bsh
(sudo) useradd tester
```

Comment: apparently the tester is in use, i am reading from the lfs book and there was no mention to make a user named tester in the first place, i messaged the person who made the walk through i am following and sent him this link and i hope to conclude this all soon.

Comment: The `userdel` command will check whether or not there are active processes running with that UID before deleting the user entry. As the user shares the UID value 0 with root and there is practically always at least one root-owned process running, it will always be "in use". In this specific case, you may have to remove the user by using `vipw` to edit the `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` files.

Comment: @telcoM I would simply edit UID/GID for the user but I didn't recommend it because it's not safe for inexperienced users.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Anyway, if the OP is following the Linux From Scratch book as mentioned in the comments, I would say this user is (or wants to be) on a rapid track for getting experienced on Linux. And this is very practical experience on the kind of problems caused by sharing UIDs (and the root UID in particular).

Comment: *"a rapid track for getting experienced on Linux"* by doing things which break the system and then cause errors which require them to ask questions here? I don't see how it might be helpful - it surely looks like it's confusing.

Comment: "The user `tester` is `root`" – Yes and no. Where the UID matters, `tester` is `root`. Where the name matters, `tester` is not `root`. Ownership is stored as UID, so *in this context* `tester` is `root`, your answer is right. But there are some settings stored in `/etc/passwd` (along with UIDs), where the name is the key. Also `/etc/group` uses usernames, not UIDs. Two names with the same UID may differ in their home directories, login shells, groups they belong to, passwords. My point is the statement "[same UID] means that the user `tester` is `root`" is not absolute.

Comment: You're right: I should have added that "In terms of permissions they are the same".